# JavaScript Web Audio API not properly connected to each other

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I have created a Web Audio API Biquad filters (Lowpass, Highpass etc) using JavaScript. The application works (I think....) well, it's displaying on the canvas without errors so i'm guessing it does. Anyway, I'm not a pro at JavaScript, far from it. I showed someone a small snippet of my code and they said it was very messy and that i'm not building my audio graph properly for example, not connecting all of the nodes from start to finish.

Now I know that the Source connects to Gain. Gain connects to Filter. Filter connects to Destination. I tried to look at it but I can't figure out what's wrong and how to fix it.

**JavaScript**

```
// Play the sound.
function playSound(buffer) {
    aSoundSource = audioContext.createBufferSource(); // creates a sound source.
    aSoundSource.buffer = buffer; // tell the source which sound to play.

    aSoundSource.connect(analyser); // Connect the source to the analyser.
    analyser.connect(audioContext.destination); // Connect the analyser to the context's destination (the speakers).

    aSoundSource.start(0); // play the source now.

    //Create Filter
    var filter = audioContext.createBiquadFilter();

    //Create the audio graph
    aSoundSource.connect(filter);

    //Set the gain node
    gainNode = audioContext.createGain();
    aSoundSource.connect(gainNode); //Connect the source to the gain node
    gainNode.connect(audioContext.destination);

    //Set the current volume
    var volume = document.getElementById('volume').value;
    gainNode.gain.value = volume;

    //Create and specify parameters for Low-Pass Filter
    filter.type = "lowpass"; //Low pass filter
    filter.frequency.value = 440;

    //End Filter
    //Connect source to destination(speaker)
    filter.connect(audioContext.destination);

    //Set the playing flag
    playing = true;

    //Clear the spectrogram canvas
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas2");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.fillStyle = "rgb(255,255,255)";
    context.fillRect (0, 0, spectrogramCanvasWidth, spectrogramCanvasHeight);

    // Start visualizer.
    requestAnimFrame(drawVisualisation);
}
```

Because of this, my volume bar thingy has stopped working. I also tried doing "Highpass filter" but it's displaying the same thing. I'm confused and have no one else to ask. By the way, the person I asked didn't help but just said it's messy...

Appreciate all of the help guys and thank you!

Answer (score 1):

So, there's a lot of context missing because of how you posted this - e.g. you don't have your drawVisualisation() code, and you don't explain exactly what you mean by your "volume bar thingy has stopped working".

My *guess* is that it's just that you have a graph that connects your source node to the output (audiocontext.destination) three times in parallel - through the analyser (which is a pass-thru, and is connected to the output), through the filter, AND through the gain node.  Your analyser in this case would show the unfiltered signal output only (you won't see any effect from the the filter, because that's a parallel signal path), and the actual output is summing three chains of the source node (one through the filter, one through the analyser, one through the gain node) - which might have some odd phasing effects, but will also triple the volume (approximately) and quite possibly clip.

Your graph looks like this:

```
source → destination
       ↳ filter → destination
       ↳ gain → destination
```

What you probably want is to connect each of these nodes in series, like this:

```
source → filter → gain → destination
```

I think you want something like this:

```
// Play the sound.
function playSound(buffer) {
  aSoundSource = audioContext.createBufferSource(); // creates a sound source.
  aSoundSource.buffer = buffer; // tell the source which sound to play.

  //Create Filter
  var filter = audioContext.createBiquadFilter();

  //Create and specify parameters for Low-Pass Filter
  filter.type = "lowpass"; //Low pass filter
  filter.frequency.value = 440;

  //Create the gain node
  gainNode = audioContext.createGain();

  //Set the current volume
  var volume = document.getElementById('volume').value;
  gainNode.gain.value = volume;

  //Set up the audio graph
  aSoundSource.connect(filter);
  filter.connect(gainNode);
  gainNode.connect(analyser);
  analyser.connect(audioContext.destination);

  aSoundSource.start(0); // play the source now.

  aSoundSource.connect(gainNode); //Connect the source to the gain node

  //Set the playing flag
  playing = true;

  //Clear the spectrogram canvas
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas2");
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  context.fillStyle = "rgb(255,255,255)";
  context.fillRect (0, 0, spectrogramCanvasWidth, spectrogramCanvasHeight);

  // Start visualizer.
  requestAnimFrame(drawVisualisation);
}
```